# Какой метод более (правильный/читаемый)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Написал несколько строк роутера, потом пришла идея переписать его на `async/await`, собственно вопрос несколько:

- Какой подход более правильный или это уже по собственному желанию?
- Есть ли вообще в данном случае смысл в `async/await`?
- Не являются ли плохой практикой вложенные промисы?
- Не является ли данный код блокирующим? У меня есть подозрение на второй кусок.

На вход идет модель User, точнее её классовые методы. `//User.options.classMethods`

В качетсве ORM идет Sequelize.

С `async/await`:

```js
module.exports = function(User) {
  router.post(`/signin`, async function(req, res) {
    const {name, password} = req.body;
    const user = await User.getUser({name});
    if(user == null) {
      let createdUser = await User.createUser({name, password});
      res.status(200).json({createdUser, msg: 'account created succeffully'});
    } else {
      res.status(422).json({"error": `user ${name} exists`});
    }
  });
  return router;
}
```

Без `async/await`:

```js
module.exports = function(User) {
  router.post(`/signin`, function(req, res) { 
    const {name, password} = req.body;
    User.getUser({name: name}).then(user => {
      if(user == null){
        User.createUser({name, password})
          .then(user => {
            res.status(200).json({user, msg: 'account created succeffully'});
        });
      } else {
        res.status(422).json({"error":`user ${name} exists`});
      }
    });
  });
  return router;
}
```

Comment: Что-то у вас в первом примере смесь промисов и async/await.

Comment: Что использовать - дело вкуса, т.к. async/await это синтаксический сахар над промисами. Мне по душе больше async/await.

Comment: Да, сделайте  `let user = await User.getUser({name});` и потом `user = await User.createUser({name, password});`

Comment: Меня тут больше смущает разнообразие кавычек (местами ненужных) и отсутствие обработки ошибки метода createUser

Comment: @AlexeyTen, В данный момент, кавычки не критичны, а вот по поводу обработки createUser учту, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл в `async/await` есть, т.к. с ним код будет более читаемый. А следовательно и его будет легче поддерживать.

Я бы сказал, что сейчас вложенные промисы это как раз плохая практика. С ними ваш код превращается в promise hell. Почти как callback hell. Лучше всего перейти на async/await.

В плане I/O оба куска неблокирующие, т.к. async/await это обёртка над промисами. А промисы под капотом уже запускаются в отдельной очереди задач. Но нужно не забывать, что некоторые независисмые операции можно объединить через `Promise.all()`.

И ещё нужно не забывать про обработку ошибок. В ноде сейчас необработанные ошибочные промисы не закрывают аварийно процесс. Поэтому нужно установить обработчик `unhandledRejection`. Также, если вы пишете роутер, то можете использовать готовый middlewaare для async/await обработчиков, [`async-middleware`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-middleware).